# Is there anyway to concatenate all user variables in an SSIS package together to put their values in an error message?

Tags: variables, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Am trying to find code that can traverse all User variables in SSIS 2008R2  so I can put their names/contents out in an error log. I want something generic so that I don't have to (for example) pass all the items into a script as read-only variables. I just want to say "what User variables are in this SSIS package and what are their contents?

does anyone know of any such code?

Comment: I'm not asking for a book or tool. I have described my problem and am asking if anyone knows the code to achieve it. I want to know if anyone knows what code can be used (C# script for example) that will allow me to traverse all user variables inside a SSIS package and concatenate them into a string, but in a generic way so I can put the code in any package and output the variables and their contents as part of an error handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User variables and their default values are stored within the xml code file that makes up each dstx (right click on dstx and View Code).

You could parse the xml file with xlst looking for DTS:Variables element followed by DTS:Variable element and then pulling out the value of DTS:ObjectName and DTS:VariableValue

If you want to do this inside a script component (without passing the xml file), you would have to add all the variable as ReadOnlyVariables so that the script can see the variables and then iterate through the list

```
        for (int i =0; i < Dts.Variables.Count ; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables[i].Name + " = " + Dts.Variables[i].Value.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment - exactly what I was looking for. Its a shame there aren't more people out there with the answers rather than ragging on the questions itself like the previous member. thanks again! (by the way, I'm using your XML parser idea since I wont necessarily know what variables are set up in what package but the idea is great)